# Beautiful Soup - identify tag based on position next to comment

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup.

Is there any way that I can get hold of a tag based on its position next to a comment (something not included in the parse tree)?

For example, let's say I have...

```
<html>
<body>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<!--text-->
<p>paragraph 3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, how might I identify `<p>paragraph 2</p>` given that I'm searching for the comment "`<!--text-->`" ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments appear in the BeautifulSoup parse tree like any other node.  For example, to find the comment with the text `some comment text` and then print out the previous `<p>` element you could do:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup('''<html>
<body>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<!--some comment text-->
<p>paragraph 3</p>
</body>
</html>''')

def right_comment(e):
    return isinstance(e, Comment) and e == 'some comment text'

e = soup.find(text=right_comment)

print e.findPreviousSibling('p')
```

... that will print out:

```
<p>paragraph 2</p>
```